# Data is not binding after the postback to the table although data is there in the model .I am doing this using asp.net Mvc

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Here is my controller code.

In this the first `GetSupplier()` function brings the data and that is shown. However after the postback the data gets changed in the model, but in the table it keeps on showing the same data.

```
 public ActionResult GetSupplier()
 {
    stm1.LocationId = int.Parse(Session["LocationId"].ToString());
    stm1.StatementType = "Select";
    stm1.ShowRecords = "Y";
    stm1.SupplierData = null;
    stm1.SupplierData = AddData.Data(stm1);
    return View(stm1);
 }


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetSupplier(string supplier)
{
    string selected;
    selected = supplier;
    //  AddData obj1 = new AddData();
    stm1.LocationId = int.Parse(Session["LocationId"].ToString());
    stm1.StatementType = "Select";
    stm1.ShowRecords = supplier;
    stm1.SupplierData = null;
    stm1.SupplierData = AddData.Data(stm1);
    return View(stm1);
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $(':radio[name="SupplierType"]').change(function () {

            var selected = $("input[type='radio'][name='SupplierType']:checked");

            var selectedVal = selected.val();
            // alert(""+selectedVal);
            $.ajax({
                url: '/SupplierType/GetSupplier',
                type: 'POST',
                data: { supplier: selectedVal },
                success: function (data) {
                    //alert(data.someValue);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>


if (Model != null && Model.SupplierData != null)
{
  <table id="assets-data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="margin-left:20%;width:60%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SupplierId</th>
            <th>Supplier Type</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var asset in Model.SupplierData)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@asset.SupplierId</td>
                <td>@asset.SupplierType</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
  </table>
}
```

Comment: If you are using AJAX to run the POST method (which is what it looks like), then the HTML table will not change unless you write some JavaScript code to change it. In your "success" function you need some code to process the data returned from the server and use it to re-draw the table.

Comment: P.S. returning a View in response to an AJAX call makes no sense, because a View is a whole page of HTML, and you cannot insert that into another page. Instead you should consider returning either a Partial View containing a new HTML table (which you can then easily use to replace the existing table in the page), or some JSON (which you can then use with some JavaScript to re-build the table to contain that new data).

Comment: Thanks for your help it is working now.